# Some machines unable to pull valid IP in particular vlan, works fine on others

Tags: networking

We have 2 computers that will not pull a DHCP address from vlan 3.  Layer 2 traffic seems to be passing for the device but not layer 3. When putting the computers in vlan 2 they pull a valid IP address.  There are 150 other devices on vlan 3 which connect and get a valid IP with no difficulties.  We are not out of DHCP leases.  When manually assigning an IP address in vlan 3 the machine communicates fine.  The machine does pull a valid IP via DHCP on other subnets.  Tried changing ports and switches to rule out flaky switch.  So, the problem doesn’t seem to be a machine problem, doesn’t seem to be a switch problem, can’t rule out route table problem but 150 other devices are successfully using the vlan 3 route through same switch and router.  Fresh thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: All connected to the same switch? or is there a trunk between switches?  Did you verify trunks are passing all VLANs you expect.

Comment: Are there IPs within the DHCP scope available?  maybe you've used all IPs in the available range...

Comment: What does "ipconfig/all" show on the client? Does the client have an APIPA address? Run a network capture on the DHCP server and run a network capture on the affected client. Then run "ipconfig/renew" on the client and look at the captures. See if the DHCP request from the client is reaching the DHCP server.

Comment: You say those machines properly get an IP when plugged to an other VLAN ... Any chance you would have some kind of static leases for those machines, in that specific VLAN? Which could explain why they're not getting anything else in the VLAN you're trying to use? Am I right to assume a single DHCP is serving all those VLANs? Anything special we'ld need to know regarding DHCP proxying?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently we had some "glitch" in the router where particular mac addresses were being blocked, a reboot of the stack (at 5 am) allowed the devices to obtain their IP.  Thank you for all the advice, it is truly appreciated.